# como hacer una consulta de 2 tablas diferentes? y poner en la misma fila

Tags: mysql, sql

Ayuda para obtener algo similar.
Como se podría hacer si el nombre de la fecha y nombre de dato es diferente.Y tambien que los valores de los datos se orden por columna, para una determinada fecha si tuviese valor colocar y si no dejar en blanco esa parte y asi sucesivamente Ejemplo

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tabla1(
>   fechaTemperatura date,
>   datoTemperatura int
>   );
>  CREATE TABLE tabla2(
>   fechaHumedad date,
>   datoHumedad int
>   );
>  INSERT INTO tabla1 VALUES 
>   ('2022-01-01',10),
>   ('2022-01-02',20),
>   ('2022-01-03',30);
>  INSERT INTO tabla2 VALUES 
>   ('2022-01-02',25),
>   ('2022-01-05',18);
> ```

Resultado Deseado:

```
   +------------+-----------------+----------------+
   | fecha      | datoTemperatura |    datoHumedad |
   +------------+-----------------+----------------+
   | 2022-01-01 | 10              |                |
   | 2022-01-02 | 20              | 25             |
   | 2022-01-03 | 30              |                |
   | 2022-01-05 |                 | 18             |
   +------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Tu pregunta esta a un voto de cierre, sugiero leas a detalle [ask]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta indicando qué has intentado, y sustituye la imagen por texto plano cortado y pegado

Comment: Está muy bien incluir datos de prueba y resultado esperado de la consulta. Sigue pendiente indicar detalles relevantes de las tablas (tipos de dato de las columnas) y, lo más importante, la consulta que no te funciona y qué error da o qué salida da diferente de la esperada. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

A riesgo de que la pregunta termine cerrada, te voy a responder porque tiene más aspecto de una duda puntual que de un ejercicio evaluable. Por favor, incluye lo que has intentado para evitar el cierre y sigue las indicaciones que te hemos dado en ésta y futuras preguntas.

La solución que buscas podrías alcanzarla así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT fecha FROM tabla1
     UNION
    SELECT fecha FROM tabla2  
  ) fechas LEFT JOIN tabla1 USING(fecha)
  LEFT JOIN tabla2 USING(fecha)
  ORDER BY fecha;
```

A partir de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla1(
  fecha date,
  dato int
  );
CREATE TABLE tabla2(
  fecha date,
  dato int
  );
INSERT INTO tabla1 VALUES 
  ('2022-01-01',10),
  ('2022-01-02',20),
  ('2022-01-03',30);
INSERT INTO tabla2 VALUES 
  ('2022-01-02',25),
  ('2022-01-05',18);
```

Obtendrías:

```
+------------+------+------+
| fecha      | dato | dato |
+------------+------+------+
| 2022-01-01 |   10 | NULL |
| 2022-01-02 |   20 |   25 |
| 2022-01-03 |   30 | NULL |
| 2022-01-05 | NULL |   18 |
+------------+------+------+
```

Comment: gracias por responder y me queda una duda como podría hacer para obtener los datos en 2 columna, osea en datos1 (valores de la tabla1) y datos 2(valores tabla2) en la misma fila de la fecha si hubiese datos. como lo especifico arriba en el resultado deseado

Comment: Sería como te indico en la edición de la respuesta. Continúas sin aportar tu intento y te estás arriesgando a que te cierren la pregunta. Y, si cambias el enunciado, deberías formular una nueva pregunta. Se trata de que queden registradas respuestas que puedan ayudar a otros usuarios, no de resolver un problema concreto. Si se te ha dado lo que has pedido, aunque no fuera lo que necesitabas, la respuesta debería haberse marcado como correcta :)

Comment: Estoy tratando de ejecutar el siguiente script: "SELECT COALESCE( t1.fechaTemperatura, t2.fechaHumedad) AS fechas,
    t1.datoTemperatura,
    t2.datoHumedad
FROM tabla1 as t1
LEFT JOIN tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.fechaTemperatura = t2.fechaHumedad " el problema con esto es que me trae todos los datos de la tabla 1 (mas la coincidencia de la tabla 2 ) pero no los datos de la tabla 2 donde no haya coincidencia, te agradecieria mucho una ayudita con esto

Comment: Te falta la subconsulta `fechas` que tienes en mi respuesta :) Si la utilizas te funcionará como indicas

Answer (score 0):

Esto se resuelve fácilmente usando un `FULL OUTER JOIN` que muestra datos de ambas tablas aunque no haya una relación.

```
SELECT COALESCE( t1.fechaTemperatura, t2.fechaHumedad) AS fecha,
    t1.datoTemperatura,
    t2.datoHumedad
FROM tabla1 AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.fechaTemperatura = t2.fechaHumedad;
```

La otra opción, en caso de que quieras que haya fechas aunque no existan en ninguna de las dos tablas, es usar una tabla de calendario y hacer un `LEFT OUTER JOIN` a esa tabla con las otras dos tablas.

```
SELECT c.fecha,
    t1.datoTemperatura,
    t2.datoHumedad
FROM Calendario c
LEFT OUTER JOIN tabla1 AS t1 ON c.fecha = t1.fechaTemperatura
LEFT OUTER JOIN tabla2 AS t2 ON c.fecha = t2.fechaHumedad;
```

Obviamente, sería buena idea limitar las fechas a mostrar de la tabla Calendario.

Comment: excelente es lo que estoy buscando, pero no se porque motivo el FULL OUTER JOIN no funciona en mySQL creo que una opcion a eso sería usar UNION

Comment: No sabía que mySQL fuera tan limitado. Intenta la opción de la tabla calendario.

Comment: utilzando SELECT COALESCE me trae lo que necesito con el otro no, otra consulta como suplantaria el full outer join con la opcion de UNION para este caso en particular

Comment: Hola Luis, aun estoy con este tema del seleccion, llegue a hacer a media  
 "SELECT COALESCE( t1.fechaTemperatura, t2.fechaHumedad) AS fechas,
    t1.datoTemperatura,
    t2.datoHumedad
FROM tabla1 as t1
LEFT JOIN tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.fechaTemperatura = t2.fechaHumedad "  como hago para que me aparezca datos de la tabla2 osea de la fecha 2022-01-05